# Cannot connect to a Node.js/Socket.io/Express server externally

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

So I'm trying to connect to my server which I've created with Node.js,Socket.io, and Express externally from the outside internet, not on my local network.
Here is my code:

Server:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});

http.listen(3000,function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Client:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      var socket = io();
      $('form').submit(function(){
        socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
        $('#m').val('');
        return false;
      });
      socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
      });
    </script>
  </body>
```

I have port forwarded port 3000. http://localhost:3000/ works, so does connecting on other computers on the same network, but I got my external IP: 12.888.999.12(random IP). I also have my port 3000. When I connect in google chrome at http://12.888.999.12:3000 does not work.

Comment: Are you trying from your own network, or a different place? I wouldn't be surprised if many routers didn't do port forwarding for traffic that originates inside and should go back inside.

Comment: You're listening on localhost. Try `http.listen(3000,'0.0.0.0')` and make sure you done port forwarding 3000 on TCP

Answer (score 1):

When you say external ip does that mean you have purchased a cloud server somewhere or its in the intranet.. Which OS are you using? is the port 3000 open on the server machine?

eg. if its a windows machine you need to go to Windows Firewall with Advanced Security and open the inbound port for TCP access

If you have done that then try this ::

```
http.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0', function() {
    console.log('Listening to port:  ' + 3000);
});
```

and then try to access with http://12.888.999.12:3000

Comment: So I'm using windows 10.  When I say external IP I mean that I went google and looked up what my ip with "what's my IP". I've opened port 3000 on the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is likely your routeur handling the query (because it know the ip belong to him) instead of fowarding it back to your server (even with port fowarding done correctly).

Side note: I had routeurs in the past that handled ANY kind of traffic (from whatever port) and always returned an 500 HTTP error.

So I would suggest you to use a [random](https://www.hurl.it/) [website](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) to test if your port is reachable from the internet then continue testing your server from your own computer using localhost.

If it is not then it could be two things :

1. Your port mapping from your router is wrong

You must use your LAN IP in the router configuration.

The source port (if you can provide one) should be the port you want to use from the internet, and the destination port should be the port from your server (here 3000)

Tests you did with computers on your lan only confirm that the firewall of your server computer is currectly configured, it didn't test anything on the router side.

2. Your ISP may block incoming traffic (it is unlikely in your case because if it does it will on standards port such as 80, 21, 8080, 443)